# Visual Studio putting web app dll in \bin\x64\debug instead of \bin\

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

IDE: Visual Studio 2010
.NET 4.0 x64 running on Windows 2008 R2 x64
All projects are configured for x64 platform.

When I compile the web application project, it puts all the required DLLs in the bin directory...HOWEVER, the web application's DLL is inside the \bin\x64\Debug.

This causes the dev web server (I use ultidev but this affects VS web server as well) to try to load the web application DLL from the \bin\ directory..but because it isn't there, it throws an exception failed to load type 'Global' (global.asax page). If I copy the web app dll from \bin\x64\debug to \bin\, it works fine.

Why isn't VS putting a copy of the web app dll to the \bin\ directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the project properties (right click on the web project, at the bottom click properties) open the "Compile" section. You should see "Build output path" with a textbox below it and a browse button. Change the build output path to "bin\"

Answer (score 2):

Due to another issue this didn't help me directly but did get me thinking.

I had to right-click on my project, "unload", then right-click again and edit the project.xml which included the outputPath variable.

That one was difference somehow so I edited it to point to "bin\", saved, right-clicked on the project one final time, choose "reload" and went about business as usual.

That solved my problem along with the issue of my break-points not being hit (because I had old files in bin\ which weren't getting cleaned up thanks to the bad path).